# Is there any way to find compound interest easily?

Tags: finance

What will be the compound interest on a sum of Rs. $25,000$ after $12$ years at the rate of $12%$ per annum?

Comment: Please make this clearer with no abbreviations if you want more people to understand. Not everyone has English as a first language. Secondly, people will be more willing to answer if you show what you know about it. You ask for an easy way. What hard way do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a formula for compound interest:
$$C=C_0(1+i)^n,$$ where:

- $C_0$ is the starting capital
- $i$ is the effective interest rate per annum
- $n$ is the number of years for which the money is in the account
- $C$ is the accumulated value (i.e. the final value) of the capital after $n$ years.

Try and apply this formula to your question.